# How to cover a ManyToOne decorator with Jest?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, typeorm, test-coverage

I have an entity with a @ManyToOne decorator on it. The problem is that my Jest unit test is not covering that single line, even though it cover others decorators.

The entity (Simplified):

```
@Entity({ name: 'user' })
export default class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  public id: string;

  @Column({ name: 'username' })
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @MinLength(3)
  @MaxLength(30)
  public username: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Account)
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'account_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  public account: Account;
```

The `typeorm` is also mocked in a `__mocks__` folder, exporting the properties used, including:

```
export const ManyToOne = jest.fn();
```

**How should I write my test with jest so it covers the ManyToOne decorator?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the non-covered line is not the entire line with the decorator, but only the body of the callback.

Since you have mocked `const ManyToOne = jest.fn();` your decorator is a function that does not have implementation and does not invokes any passed callback.

So if you mock it as a function which immediately executes and returns the result of the given callback

```
export const ManyToOne = jest.fn(callback => callback());
```

you should be able to achieve 100% coverage of that line

Comment: Perfect. It does makes sense, since this decorator was the only one which receives a callback as argument